# store the text-box value in arrays

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

i have one html page in them one text-box

```
<input type="text" id="region&activity">

<input type="button" id="result" value="submit">
```

in text-box i am entered `Race in Gujarat` i want to store this value in to Array
something. `Race` in one array and `Gujarat` in another array
help me or give some idea to do this.
thanks

Comment: What is your split point among region?

Comment: What are you working with, PHP? Java?

Comment: @Neo i want to split before and after `in` value

Comment: @buymypies PHP is good for me...

Comment: A google for 'php split string' might point towards the answer

Comment: Do you wish to perform this server-side or client-side?

Comment: @JackPhp what you tried...

Comment: @jacklanza i am try to get javascript and ajax to do this...

Comment: check my answer... i hope this is use full to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use java script then do something this type:-

```
<script>
    $(function(){
$("#filter").click(function(){
    var name = $('#select').val();
    alert(name);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {"name":name} ,
        url: "array.php",
        async: false,       
        success: function(result) { 
        alert(result);
        $("#result").text(result);
        } 
    });   


    });
});
    </script>
```

this is your html code:-

```
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="select">
    <input  type="button" id="filter" name="button" value="Search">
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is array.php:-

```
<?php
$name= $_POST['name'];
$result =  explode("in", $name);
foreach($result as $row){
echo $row;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?php
 $abc='race in gujrat';
 list($event,$state) = split('in',$abc);
  echo $event;
 echo $state;
 ?>
```

and store that string in array

Comment: as lanza answer php file how to set our this php file... i want to both array in different as per your answer...

Comment: store $event in one array and $state in another array...like this       $array1[]=$event; and $array2[]=$state;

Comment: yes but i am try to post something like this `<?php
 $abc= $_POST['name'];
 list($event,$state) = split('in',$abc);
  echo $event;
 echo $state;
 ?>` as per @jacklanza answer.

Comment: i got the error something like this `Function split() is deprecated in C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\SVN\php\array.php on line 4`

Comment: means u r asking about ....when button submit u want to post this into different array?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27086/discussion-between-thumber-nirmal-and-jack-php)

Comment: check my this answer:-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678561/store-the-text-box-value-in-arrays/15680664#15680664

Answer (score 1):

**Using PHP**

This result assumes you are splitting them into an array after the space.

```
$text  = "Race in Gujarat";
$result =  explode(" ", $text);
echo $result[0];  //Race
echo $result[1];  //in
echo $result[2];  //Gujarat
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question isn't clearly defined, I'm assuming that you wish to remove the word "in", and split the the string into separate arrays on the space character.

How about (using jQuery for convenience):

```
var splitRegion=$("#region&activity").val().replace(/in /g," ").split(" ");
myArray1.push(splitRegion[0]);
myArray2.push(splitRegion[1]);
```

By the way, I believe an ampersand (&) is an illegal character in an id.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
<?php
 $abc= $_POST['name'];
 list($event,$state) = explode('in',$abc);

 $array1[]=$event;
 $array2[]=$state;
 foreach($array1 as $city)
{
echo $city;
}
foreach($array2 as $st)
{
echo $st;
}
 ?>
```